# Sorting a SQL query by number of fields in a grouped selection

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

I have this table,

```
CREATE TABLE `Products` (
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `added_by` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `list_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=231 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

and i want an sql query such that i get groups of same-named products ordered by which group has the most entries at the top and fewest at the bottom

This is what i have so far, but it only sorts the groups alphabetically

```
SELECT product FROM Products GROUP BY product ORDER BY product
```

what do i add to the end of this to count and sort by the number of entries in each group?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT product, COUNT(*) AS NumberOfEntries 
FROM Products 
GROUP BY product 
ORDER BY NumberOfEntries DESC
```

Read more about aggregate functions [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
SELECT product
FROM
(
    SELECT product, COUNT( 1 ) AS num_products
    FROM products
    GROUP BY product
) AS t
ORDER BY num_products DESC
```